# Is it possible to monitor the camera status from the lightning port?

Tags: iphone, ios

Is it possible for a device connected to the lightning port to tell whether or not the camera is currently recording?

Could you have a dongle with an LED that lights up automatically like an “on air” sign while the camera is recording?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: @Allan Sorry I’m not sure what you mean. What information is missing?

Comment: Questions should include a single problem. You can [ask another question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) including the other problem. The missing information could be : What have you tried and in which ways didn't it work? What is you apparatus (be more specific - what "device" are you using? etc.)? etc.

Comment: They way the question is written, it’s a simple answer - “Yes”. Since  the Lightning signal doesn’t carry a “camera light indicator;” it only carries data you’ll need to engineer whatever you’re building in hardware and software to illuminate that light.  Unfortunately we can walk you through either of these processes as they would be off topic here.  However, if you have a *specific* question about something related to Apple, it can be asked here.

Comment: Well thank you both for the warm welcome. Bye.